# Access a variable within a dictionary with unknown nested location

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file and I want to query it using python. However, I do not know the nested location of a variable before hand. E.g. to query a JSON object below loaded into python and called 'data', I could do the following:

```
data['experiments']['initial_ns']['icdat']
```

However, this assumes that I know that the `icdat` variable is located below `initial_ns` which is located under `experiments`. Unfortunately I do not have this information and also the JSON structure could change in the future. Is there a simpler variable to access variables within a JSON string without explicitly specifying the entire structure?

thanks!!!

```
{
    "experiments": [
        {
            "management": {
                "events": [
                    {
                        "date": "19122", 
                        "timp": "TI3", 
                        "eve": "tage"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "initial_ns": {
                "icpcr": "MZ", 
                "icdat": "1922"
            }, 
            "observed": {
                "mdat": "19403", 
                "time_series": [
                    {
                        "date": "198423", 
                        "etac": "0"
                    }
                ], 
                "adat": "190218"
            }, 
            "local_name": "lhi", 
            "exname": "SE", 
            "exp_dur": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can iterate over the dictionary / list.

Comment: What **can** you assume accurately about the data? Just that 'icdat' exists somewhere within the structure at any point?

Comment: _I do not know the nested location of a variable before hand._ and _Unfortunately I do not have this information and also the JSON structure could change in the future._ is something like **You will learn what you are eating after you taste it, it might be poison or something else, and you have to taste it if you wish to learn**. That kind of data must be in a unchanglable format and you must know what you willl get and from where you will get it.

Comment: I agree with @FallenAngel. It would be a highly inefficient situation for you to be working with a completely random nested JSON structure and have to always find a key at some random point. You would never know what kind of structure it is nested beneath unless you looped over the entire thing, test each child type, and loop deeper until you find what you want.

Comment: Oh, and your example `data['experiments']['initial_ns']['icdat']` does not work for this data structure, because `experiments` is a list. You would have to index: `data['experiments'][0]['initial_ns']['icdat']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the jsonpath module. http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/. I think the search string $..icdat will match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> "...*without explicitly specifying the entire structure?*"

Yes, there are many ways. Unfortunately you have not specified which answer you are looking for.

To be "unique in terms of the schema" (my terminology) is as follows: If you have for example multiple Foo dictionaries with the key Foo.bar, then that is still unique. What is not unique is if you have Foo objects with Foo.bar, and Baz objects with Baz.bar: searching for `{... baz:...}` will return different kinds of objects.

If the key is unique in terms of the schema, you can search the entire tree. You can make this go faster by caching all key-value pairs in a dictionary for later use (therefore the operation is O(1) "instant" amortized cost, since you needed to go through the entire data structure anyway to parse it!). This even works if you would like to return sets of objects: use a `cache = collections.defaultdict(set)` and when you preprocess items to cache, do `cache[key].add(value)`.

If the key is not unique in terms of the schema, you will want to make a reasonable guess about the path and provide some partial information, per Hans Then's answer utilization JsonPath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12291240/711085 (alternatively, change the schema)

Comment: Nice explanation. I like the part where you address the schema and how it will impact the ability to simply look up an item by its "basename" key.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to recursively search nested containers for a given key, similar to `findElementByID()` in an XML DOM parser.

```
def find_key(json, key):
    if isinstance(json, dict):
        if key in json:
            yield json[key]
    if isinstance(json, (dict, list)):
        for value in (json.itervalues() if isinstance(json, dict) else json):
            if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
                for item in find_key(value, key):
                    yield item

>>> next(items_by_key(data, "icdat"))
'1922'
```

Since the same key may be found in multiple places in the document, this is actually written as a generator. You can iterate over the results to get all the values or, if you just want the first one (or know it's the only one), use `next()` around it as I've shown above. You could also convert it to a `list()` if desired.

Comment: Just a note - Finds **first** occurrence of `key` in `json`

Comment: Maybe not the *first* -- dictionaries are unordered, so the ordering in the original JSON will be lost. But good point; best to use this approach only when you know a key is unique.

Comment: Actually, this would be very easy to convert to a generator that yields multiple items if multiple values with a given key are found; let me do that.

Comment: It's a cool idea. Almost there...but has a hiccup if the value is a string:  key = 'local_name' . It loops the string characters.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to know the format, or you'll have to manually loop over everything in it.